# Wordpress Site 'hiding' content when removing left margin

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am adjusting a Wordpress site using twenty fourteen theme.

I have removed the left sidebar - i did this by simply commenting out the php code.

Whilst the sidebar div is now removed, when i try to remove the margin-left that moves all the the other content 222px  it hides the content.

Here is the website

http://pacificwhiteboards.com.au/product/communicate-corporate-magnetic-whiteboards/

Any ideas ? I am at a bit of a loss.

Thankyou

James.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the custom css to remove the whitespace:

```
.site:before {
    display: none;
}
```

Then you can center your site content adding:

```
.full-width .site-content {
    margin:0px auto;
}
.full-width .site-content .has-post-thumbnail .entry-header {
    margin:0px auto;
}
.singular.full-width .site-content .has-post-thumbnail.hentry {
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

Also, I know you didn't ask about it, but I noticed some whitespace on your fixed header, you can get rid of it with a little more css:

```
.masthead-fixed .site-header {
max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Look for the `.site:before` CSS selectors; it's injecting content, and that's what's covering your stuff. When I removed all the '.site:before' rules, it seemed to work fine, though I don't know the theme itself well enough to say that there won't be other tweaks you'll need to make.